# XML parsing and foreach structure

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, foreach

I'm new to XML parsing but not new to php and html. I need to parse the following XML structure:

```
<er_data service="pl">
    <manufacturer_item>
        <item_id></item_id>
        <model></model>
        <manufacturer></manufacturer>
        <product_name></product_name>
        <description></description>
        <datasheeturl/>
        <image_url/>
        <map></map>
    </manufacturer_item>
    <dealers>
        <dealer id="111">
            <dealer_logo>http:/source.com/images/vendors/90x60/111.gif</dealer_logo>
            <dealer_name></dealer_name>
            <dealer_url></dealer_url>
        </dealer>
        <dealer id="222">
            <dealer_logo>http:/source.com/images/vendors/90x60/222.gif</dealer_logo>
            <dealer_name></dealer_name>
            <dealer_url></dealer_url>
        </dealer>
    </dealers>
    <dealer_item>
        <dealer_id>111</dealer_id>
        <dealer_sku></dealer_sku>
        <model></model>
        <manufacturer></manufacturer>
        <name></name>
        <price></price>
        <availability></availability>
        <image_url></image_url>
        <buy_url>http://source.com/c/?nVID=111&rsSku=321321</buy_url>
    </dealer_item>
    <dealer_item>
        <dealer_id>222</dealer_id>
        <dealer_sku></dealer_sku>
        <model></model>
        <manufacturer></manufacturer>
        <name></name>
        <price></price>
        <availability></availability>
        <image_url></image_url>
        <buy_url>http://source.com/c/?nVID=222&rsSku=654654</buy_url>
    </dealer_item>
    <loggingpixel></loggingpixel>
</er_data>
```

and create a foreach that outputs html like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><img src=$dealer_logo></td>
<td><a href=$buy_url>Buy Online</a></td>
</tr>
```

For brevity, I'm not putting all the things I've tried. There will be one manufacturer item and it will be a constant. There will be multiple dealer id (s) and each dealer could have multiple dealer_item (s) but will always have at least one. I don't know the constructs to use to get the things I need. The dealer_logo comes out of dealers and the buy_url comes out of dealer_items. Note the logo URL will have the dealer id number in it.

For brevity, I won't show all the newbie things I've tried. Basically, I am using a structure like this for the reading and looping:

```
$retailers = simplexml_load_file("http://source.com/xml.asp");

foreach ($retailers->dealer_items as $storeinfo):
endforeach;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Sorry that the XML is not indented properly.
Karen
edit
MrCode- I'm still getting nothing. The XML file is under someone else's control but when I open it in Safari and save it to disk I see &. I also changed the URL that I feed it to have the & but still nothing. Here is the code exactly as I have it currently:

```
<table class="gridtable">
<tr>
    <th>Retailer</th>
    <th>In Stock</th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>

<?php   
$retailers = simplexml_load_string('http://pg.links.channelintelligence.com/pages/plxml.asp?sSKU=633472600401&amp;nRGID=4938');
$dealers = array();
foreach($retailers->dealers->dealer as $dealer)
{
$dealers[(int)$dealer->attributes()->id] = array('dealer_logo' => (string)$dealer->dealer_logo);
}
?>

<?php foreach($retailers->dealer_item as $item): ?>
<tr>
<td><img src="<?php echo $dealers[(int)$item->dealer_id]['dealer_logo']; ?>"></td>
<td>Yes</td>
<td><a href="<?php echo (string)$item->buy_url; ?>">Buy Online</a></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

edit (strugging with formatting on the forum) *The XML file is under someone else's control but when I open it in Safari and save it to disk I see the encoded version of ampersand.

Edit to post errors:
[Mon Aug 12 20:32:06 2013] [error] [client 204.181.48.224] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home/sites/staging.clearblueeasy.com/website/m/advanced-digital-ovulation-test-buyonline.php on line 32
[Mon Aug 12 20:32:06 2013] [error] [client 204.181.48.224] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): http://pg.links.channelintelligence.com/pages/plxml.asp?nrgid=4938&ssku=63347260 in /home/sites/staging.clearblueeasy.com/website/m/advanced-digital-ovulation-test-buyonline.php on line 32
[Mon Aug 12 20:32:06 2013] [error] [client 204.181.48.224] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /home/sites/staging.clearblueeasy.com/website/m/advanced-digital-ovulation-test-buyonline.php on line 32
[Mon Aug 12 20:32:06 2013] [error] [client 204.181.48.224] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/sites/staging.clearblueeasy.com/website/m/advanced-digital-ovulation-test-buyonline.php on line 34
[Mon Aug 12 20:32:06 2013] [error] [client 204.181.48.224] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/sites/staging.clearblueeasy.com/website/m/advanced-digital-ovulation-test-buyonline.php on line 40

Comment: So what's the problem? You know how to foreach. You know how to traverse the SimpleXml. Just get the data you want and write into your HTML strings.

Comment: `$retailers->dealer_items` should be `$retailers->dealer_item` from there you can normally read the rest what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have the dealers defined separately in the XML, you will need to first extract the dealers, so that you can lookup the `dealer_logo` based on the ID in the `dealer_item`:

```
<?php
// assume $retailers is the xml object
$dealers = array();
foreach($retailers->dealers->dealer as $dealer)
{
    $dealers[(int)$dealer->attributes()->id] = array('dealer_logo' => (string)$dealer->dealer_logo);
}
?>

<?php foreach($retailers->dealer_item as $item): ?>
<tr>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $dealers[(int)$item->dealer_id]['dealer_logo']; ?>"></td>
    <td><a href="<?php echo (string)$item->buy_url; ?>">Buy Online</a></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Edit: [Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/c7OGj37e)

Make sure that your XML is valid. Take a look at your URLs in the XML, they contain raw `&` which is not valid. You need to encode them into `&amp;`. In the demo, I have changed them so you can see the code working.

Edit 2: final code

```
<?php

$retailers = simplexml_load_file('http://pg.links.channelintelligence.com/pages/plxml.asp?sSKU=633472600401&nRGID=4938');

$dealers = array();
foreach($retailers->dealers->dealer as $dealer)
{
    $dealers[(int)$dealer->attributes()->id] = array('dealer_logo' => (string)$dealer->dealer_logo);
}

?>

<?php foreach($retailers->dealer_items->dealer_item as $item): ?>
<tr>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $dealers[(int)$item->dealer_id]['dealer_logo']; ?>"></td>
    <td><a href="<?php echo (string)$item->buy_url; ?>">Buy Online</a></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Mr. Code, that looks elegant to me and that is the problem- that dealers are defined separately. But I can't get anything to populate. I don't want to ignore the obvious - to define $retailers I'm using:                                                      <?php
        $retailers = simplexml_load_file("http://source.com/plxml.asp");
?> I tried putting a static image in for logo and just pulling the buy_url and am getting nothing for it either. Thx, Karen

Comment: @Karen, see my edit - added demo. Remember to encode `&` into `&amp;` in the XML or SimpleXML will not be able to parse it.

Comment: see my edit. Thanks for the demo. I'm sorry to say I still can't make it work.

Comment: Why does your URL to the xml have `&amp;`? That seems to be causing the problem, change to `&` so it becomes `http://pg.links.channelintelligence.com/pages/plxml.asp?sSKU=633472600401&nRGID=4938`

Comment: I tried it thinking that was the only way simplexml_load_string would work. I switched back to &. I also tried simplexml_load_file. But nothing is working.

Comment: I tried saving off the xml file locally and loading. I simplified the code to just try to echo one thing. It just doesn't seem to be loading the xml at all. Are there tests I can run to see if it's loading/parsing? Way back when I first started I remember seeing some of the XML printing at the top of the page when I displayed it in FF so I assumed it was loading in some way but that was so far back in my edits I can't replicate even that now.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `buy_url`'s from your local XML version? If it does then it's got to be those `&` in there.

Comment: The feed doesn't have plain & in there it has the encoded one the & plus amp plus ; (everytime I write it out it goes back to just & in the post, how do I get it not change it).

Comment: After you load the XML with `simplexml_load_file()` - the local file. Do `var_dump($retailers);` and see what it outputs, just to see if it's parsing any xml.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be parsing. Seems to repeat in patterns like this: object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (5) { ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["item_count"]=> string(1) "1" ["error_count"]=> string(0) "" ["service"]=> string(2) "pl" } ["manufacturer_item"]=>

Comment: Now remove the second foreach and just leave the first one in (the one that pulls out dealer data) and after it do `print_r($dealers)` or `var_dump($dealers)` to see if it managed to get the dealer data.

Comment: Yes, it's getting the dealers. Pattern like this: Array ( [11302] => Array ( [dealer_logo] => http://content.channelintelligence.com/images/vendors/90x60/11302.gif ) ) Array ( [11302] => Array ( [dealer_logo] => http://content.channelintelligence.com/images/vendors/90x60/11302.gif )

Comment: And I've also put the live http: feed back in instead of local file and it works as well.

Comment: Ok try adding something simple like `foreach($retailers->dealer_item as $item){ echo (string)$item->buy_url; }` and see if it outputs the urls.

Comment: I added this <?php
foreach($retailers->dealer_item as $item)
 { echo (string)$item->buy_url; 
 }
?> down in the html section where the table is. I moved the rest up to the very top of page in case that would do anything. It outputs nothing - this is where it breaks but why did it work on your example. Trying to figure out what is different.

Comment: Have a look in your error log to see if there's any clues because it is strange that the first part works and second doesn't.

Comment: I posted the errors above in the edit: they range from what seems like problems on the XML side to invalid arguments on the php side. I'm starting to feel like XML is a finicky thing to tackle.

Comment: The problem is there is an extra tag in the xml that wraps around the dealer_item e.g. `<dealer_items><dealer_item>` and the XML in the question doesn't show this :) so to resolve you need to change the second foreach (see my edit2). Also be sure to use `simplexml_load_file` for external not `_string`.

Comment: It's working! Thanks for sticking with me on this. I just wrote an unhappy email to the company providing the XML feed. The schema that they provided to us at launch left out the <dealer_items> set of tags. Shame on me for not doublechecking it against the live feed.